# Disable date for selected days in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datepicker

I have an online appointment form in my Laravel application with some filed `Select Doctor` and `datepicker`.

Suppose doctor `A` will be available in clinic at Saturday, Monday and Wednesday. And doctor `B` will be available at Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday. So while any patient choose doctor `A` from the `Select Doctor` field, all the dates with Saturday, Monday and Wednesday will be activated in the `datepicker` calendar and other dates will be deactivated.

I have already deactivated some selected dates of `datepicker` calendar. But can't disable date for selected days in `datepicker`.

**html**

```
<input class="form-control" id="appointment_datepicker" name="appointment_datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Select Date" value="{{ $user->appointment_datepicker or old('appointment_datepicker') }}">
```

**ajax**

```
    $.ajax({

      url:"{{ url('/filter_available_date') }}",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {_token :token, branch_id_appointment : branch_id_appointment, doctor_id_appointment : doctor_id_appointment},
      success:function(msg){

        $('#appointment_datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date){
                var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [ msg.indexOf(day) == -1 ] //here msg is the Array of selected Dates which are activated in the datepicker calendar
            });                    
    }
});
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/filter_available_date','frontendAppointmentController@filter_available_date');
```

**controller**

```
public function filter_available_date(Request $request)
{
    $branch_id = $request->branch_id_appointment;
    $doctor_id = $request->doctor_id_appointment;    
    $query =  DB::table('service_doctors');
    $query->select('doctor_id','inactive_dates_in_this_month');    
    if($branch_id != '0')
        $query->where('branch_id','=', $branch_id);

    if($doctor_id != NULL)
        $query->where('doctor_id','=', $doctor_id);

    $result_time = $query->get();    
    $result = [$result_time[0]->inactive_dates_in_this_month];    
    $final_result= explode(',',$result[0]);    
    return $final_result;
}
```

**Calendar**
[image]

How to solve the issue ? Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it jquery datepicker?

Comment: @EhsanMahmud...yes

Comment: Can you provide the API response?

Comment: @EhsanMahmud....I am new in Laravel. Will you tell me the procedure to find the API response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Every day has a fix number like

```
Sunday = 0
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday = 5
Saturday = 6
```

So an `Array` of day's number(**ex : var arr = [1, 2, 3];**) return from the controller and those day will be active in the `datepicker`.

Just change the below code in Ajax

**Ajax**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3] //these are the array of days numbers return from controller

$('#appointment_datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function(date){
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(arr.indexOf(day) != -1)];
    });
```

So here only `Monday`,`Tuesday` and `Wednesday` will active in the `datepicker` calendar.

[image]

Comment: Now I understand what you wanted. What you wrote on the post, meant that you already had the dates coming from the database table, you actually wanted days filtered, not dates. Which is why necessary to see the api response :).

Answer (score 3):

From the first look, it seems like a problem of date mismatch. If you use the example below, you can see how the data coming from the API should look like.

```js
var msg = ["2020-05-11"];
$('#appointment_datepicker').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [msg.indexOf(day) == -1]
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="appointment_datepicker" name="appointment_datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Select Date">
```

Comment: .....I can successfully deactivate specific dates which are in the array....but can't deactivate dates for specific Days.Hope you understand my problem. I have updated my post with API response

Comment: So, the patient selects a doctor and the calendar changes, is that what you want to do?

Comment: No !!.... From the admin panel I have select offDay for each doctor....and patient will see the offDay as deactivate in calendar for the selected doctor....So I want, how to convert those offDays as a deactivate date in datepicker calendar

Comment: Umm, honestly, your question doesn't really reflect what you have presented in the post. It seemed like you are just not being able to disable dates. This sounds more like a task. Can you please pinpoint to the Controllers where you are sending the offDay and how it's received in the ajax call?

Comment: I have updated my post with controller and routes.please have a look

Comment: Again, I come back to what I posted in my answer. It looks like you are not returning the correct date format. Check the msg variable again, and match that against your response from the API. If you don't know how to inspect that, you can find out by searching in google for "monitor ajax calls for [your browser]". For firefox, you can right click on the screen > inspect > network to see what requests are happening and click on your corresponding request to find out the response value from api.

Comment: .....I think either I can't properly describe or u can't properly understand...But thanks for your patient brother. I solve it.